# Customise choices for BooleanWidget in django_filters

Tags: django, django-views, django-filter

I'm using django_filters. For boolean fields, it generates this HTML:

```
<select name="bass" id="id_bass">
  <option value="">Unknown</option>
  <option value="true" selected="">Yes</option>
  <option value="false">No</option>

</select>
```

This springs from [Django's own specifics of NullFields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/widgets/). How can I change that ugly 'Unknown' to something else? the user is not really searching for 'Unknown'; they're searching for 'all', since my boolean field is required and either `true` or `false`.

The widget does not accept a `choices` attribute.

Creating manually the HTML myself partially solved the issue; nevertheless, I would achieve this from the `view` and use only the `{{form}}` on the template.

**PS**

The best way of doing it on the template is by simply running this JavaScript after the DOM has loaded:

```
    document.getElementById('id_bass').options[0].innerText = "---------";
```

A bit hacky; still, it does what I want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a custom widget for that and can use it in your `BooleanFilter()` as,

```
from django_filters.widgets import BooleanWidget
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _


class CustomBooleanWidget(BooleanWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.choices = (("", _("Anything else")), ("true", _("Yes")), ("false", _("No")))


class YourFilterSet(filters.FilterSet):
    your_field = filters.BooleanFilter(widget=CustomBooleanWidget)

    class Meta:
        model = YourModelClass
        fields = ("your_field",)
```